# Combining results with Chinese remainder theorem - general case

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

suppose we have a congruence

$$
ax^2+bx+c\equiv 0 \mod (p_1\cdot p_2)
$$

being $p_1$ and $p_2$ primes - actually it should be possible to extend these considerations to an arbitrary number of primes - but let's keep it easy.

We know that the congruence has solution if and only if have solution the congruences:

$$
ax^2+bx+c\equiv 0 \mod p_1
$$

and

$$
ax^2+bx+c\equiv 0 \mod p_2
$$

Suppose the congruences have solutions:

$$ x\equiv s_1 \mod p_1$$
$$ x\equiv s_2 \mod p_1$$

and

$$ x\equiv t_1 \mod p_2$$
$$ x\equiv t_2 \mod p_2$$

I know I need to combine these results with CRT to find the (four, in this case) results modulo $p_1\cdot p_2$ of the original congruence. The problem is **how?**

I know that the CRT gives only one congruence, as a result, so my surmise is that I should combine the results as follows:

1. $x\equiv s_1 \mod p_1$ and $ x\equiv t_1 \mod p_2$
2. $x\equiv s_2 \mod p_1$ and $ x\equiv t_1 \mod p_2$
3. $x\equiv s_1 \mod p_1$ and $ x\equiv t_2 \mod p_2$
4. $x\equiv s_2 \mod p_1$ and $ x\equiv t_2 \mod p_2$

**Is that correct?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, that is correct. (We are assuming $p_1$ and $p_2$ are distinct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is correct.  The reasoning for why it is correct is just logic, and is as follows.

- *All* solutions to the first congruence are given by *those integers $x$* such that $x \equiv s_1 \text{ or } s_2 \mod p_1$.
- *All* solutions to the second congruence are given by *those integers $x$* such that $x \equiv t_1 \text{ or } t_2 \mod p_2$.
- Thus, an integer satisfies *both* congruences if and only if it is in *both* sets of integers, i.e.
  we need $(x \equiv s_1 \text{ or } s_2 \mod p_1)$ AND $(x \equiv t_1 \text{ or } t_2 \mod p_2)$.  Which is equivalent to the four possibilities you list:

  1. $x\equiv s_1 \mod p_1$ and $ x\equiv t_1 \mod p_2$, OR
  2. $x\equiv s_2 \mod p_1$ and $ x\equiv t_1 \mod p_2$, OR
  3. $x\equiv s_1 \mod p_1$ and $ x\equiv t_2 \mod p_2$, OR
  4. $x\equiv s_2 \mod p_1$ and $ x\equiv t_2 \mod p_2$.

Then you solve each of the four cases with Chinese Remainder Theorem.